# Best Way to Check if a Word is Valid from a .txt

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create some kind of a word game using Unity with C#. I want my app to be working offline, so I can't use web API's. I found a text file of nearly 55k words, but what would be the most optimized way of using it? I just want to check if the String entered is a valid word. I'm guessing I can't just create a list of 55k elements and check every one of them, even with sorting algorithms. So, how can other apps achieve this without destroying my device? What is the secret? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `55k` English words are not that great volume. Assuming each word being `10` unicode characters (which seems to be an overestimation) we can expect
the required space to be `2 * 55000 * 10` ~ `1 MB`. To validate words efficiently (scanning `55k` lines can be time consuming), try using `HashSet<string>`:

```
  using System.IO;
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  HashSet<string> allValidWords = new HashSet<string>(File
    .ReadLines(@"c:\myWords.txt")
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    .Select(line => line.Trim()), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Then use `Contains` for validating:

```
 string myWord = "Jabberwocky";

 ...

 if (allValidWords.Contains(myWord)) {
   // myWord is valid
 }  
 else {
   // myWord is not valid
 }
```

Comment: So is it OK to use this method to check every time my user enters a word? I guess I'm underestimating how powerful computers are... Thank you so much, will be doing just that. I thought an array -or a HashSet for this matter- would be the worst for memory management or optimization. Thank you again!

Comment: @tetradev: read the file *once* (i.e. `HashSet<string> allValidWords = ...`) on program starting, then validate (`if (allValidWords.Contains(myWord)) {...}`) as many as required

Comment: @tetradev Finding an entry in a HashSet is O(1) - it runs in constant time; it's extremely fast.

Answer (score -1):

Use `SQLite` and store all words in a table. It's commands are very similar to `SQL server` and deploying it requires nothing but a `dll`. It is very fast and usefull for such purposes.

Please refer to the following link:
[sqlite.org](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

> Note: Be careful of saving data in local storages like text or dbs. Hackers can mode your game very easily.

Comment: OK, guess this will be way faster than using a HashSet? I don't really care about people hacking my game as this project is not that serious. But I don't know how to create a file outside a compiled Unity Project, but I guess that's another topic? Thank you so much.

Comment: I doubt it will be faster than a HashSet! The HashSet already is completely loaded into runtime memory .. it will probably take longer to look it up via SQL queries every time

Answer (score -2):

You might want to use SQLite package and store all these words in a table. It is much more efficient then reading from txt files as it is relational and easy to query.

just query it with the most simplest sql query

select COLUMNS from TABLE where 'your_word' IN (..,..)